# Parall execution of one Function with different parameters in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Thank you for your answer. I need to get execution time with package future. Unfortunately when I start system.time it shows not the time that I need. And nothing is being executed. Any ideas?

```
system.time( {
  library("future")
  plan(multiprocess)
  source("ARIMAX_2018.R")
  FLO_1_18<- readRDS("RDS/FLO_1_18.rds")
  FLO_1_17<- readRDS("RDS/FLO_1_17.rds")
  foo1<-deparse(substitute(FLO_1_18))
  foo1
  FLO_1_18 %<-% ARIMAX_2018(FLO_1_18, FLO_1_17, foo1)
})

system.time( {

  source("ARIMAX_2018.R")
  FLO_1_18<- readRDS("RDS/FLO_1_18.rds")
  FLO_1_17<- readRDS("RDS/FLO_1_17.rds")
  foo1<-deparse(substitute(FLO_1_18))
  foo1
  FLO_1_18<-ARIMAX_2018(FLO_1_18, FLO_1_17, foo1)
})
```

I tried profvis and future but strangely it takes too long to execute my R code and R session breaks. Additionally I get Qt Qtwebengineprocess running in Rstudio. How can I resolve my issue?

The code below with 16 "futures" did well. But when I started one more file with 32 ones do not get any output. Is there a problem that too many "futures" are being executed at once? Thank you.

```
##rm(list=ls())
##profvis({

  library("future")
  plan(multiprocess)


  source("Flex_Function/Flex_FLO_2019.R")
  FLO_1_19<- readRDS("RDS/FLO_1_19.rds")
  foo1<-deparse(substitute(FLO_1_19))
  foo1
  FLO_1_19 %<-% FLEX_FLO_2019(FLO_1_19,foo1)

  ###################GRH_6_19
  source("Flex_Function/Flex_GRH_2019.R")
  GRH_6_19<- readRDS("RDS/GRH_6_19.rds")
  foo1<-deparse(substitute(GRH_6_19))
  foo1
  GRH_6_19 %<-% FLEX_GRH_2019(GRH_6_19,foo1)

  ####################GRIM_1_19
  source("Flex_Function/Flex_GRIM_2019.R")
  GRIM_1_19<- readRDS("RDS/GRIM_1_19.rds")
  foo1<-deparse(substitute(GRIM_1_19))
  foo1
  GRIM_1_19 %<-% FLEX_GRIM_2019(GRIM_1_19,foo1)
  ##############

  ##################GRIM_2_19
  source("Flex_Function/Flex_GRIM_2019.R")
  GRIM_2_19<- readRDS("RDS/GRIM_2_19.rds")
  foo1<-deparse(substitute(GRIM_2_19))
  foo1
  GRIM_2_19 %<-% FLEX_GRIM_2019(GRIM_2_19,foo1)
  ##############
```

Comment: It says it cannot find the function definition. Where is `ARIMAX_2018` defined? If it's allegedly defined in `"ARIMAX_2018.R"`, then I think you need to source the file again, look for warnings/errors ([edit] and add if you find some), check for typos (mis-spelling), and try again. There's little we can do to help since we know nothing about the function or the data.

Comment: I have tried tested futures with

Comment: (1) While it is feasible to have more processes/threads than you *need* (slowing things down a little), I can think of no situation where extra threads cause a different (or missing) output. (2) Your use of `deparse(substitute(...))` seems wholly unnecessary. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Thank you. With deparse(substitute(...)) I pass that the name as parameter

Comment: Why not just `foo1 <- "FLO_1_19"`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I still can not figure out why it is not possible to evaluate execution time of future expression with profvis or system.time. Could somebody please help me? Thank you